# c# multiple lock for multiple events

Tags: c#, events, locking

I'm trying to understand the lock mechanism.
if I have multiple events to lock on different value should I use an object lock for each?
More serious code added:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Threading;

 namespace ValueChangeOnEventForm
 {

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Test_Onchange DataSource;
    Thread Task1;
    private bool Flag_Stop_Task1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        graph1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
        graph1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
        graph1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 100;
        graph2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
        graph2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
        graph2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 100;

        DataSource = new Test_Onchange();
        DataSource.ValueChanged += new   EventHandler(EventValueChange);//Value input info
        DataSource.SecondValueChange += new EventHandler(EventSecondValueChange);//second value

        Task1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Task_1));//create the thread
        Task1.Start();//start the thread
    }
    protected virtual void EventSecondValueChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double valueMAX = 0, size = 0;

        if (graph1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            graph1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { graph1.Series["ValueOnGraph"].Points.AddY(DataSource.Value); }));
            graph1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { valueMAX = graph1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum; }));
            graph1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { size = graph1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size; }));
            if (valueMAX - 10 > size)
            {
                graph1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { graph1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Scroll(graph1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum); }));
                graph1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { graph1.Series["ValueOnGraph"].Points.RemoveAt(0); }));
            }
        }
    }
    protected virtual void EventValueChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double valueMAX=0,size=0;

        if (graph2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            graph2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { graph2.Series["ValueOnGraph2"].Points.AddY(DataSource.Secondvalue); }));
            graph2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { valueMAX = graph2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum; }));
            graph2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { size = graph2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size; }));
            if (valueMAX - 10 > size)
            {
                graph2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { graph2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Scroll(graph2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum); }));
                graph2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { graph2.Series["ValueOnGraph2"].Points.RemoveAt(0); }));
            }
        }
    }
    private void Task_1()
    {
        while (!Flag_Stop_Task1)
        {
            Random RandVal = new Random();
            Random RandVal2 = new Random();

            int Value = RandVal.Next(0, 100);
            int SecondValue = RandVal2.Next(50, 200);

            DataSource.Value = Value;
            DataSource.Secondvalue = SecondValue;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Flag_Stop_Task1 = false;
    }

    private void btn_StopTask_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Flag_Stop_Task1 = true;
    }
}   
}
```

And then

```
 namespace ValueChangeOnEventForm
 {
 class Test_Onchange
 {
    private int value;
    private int secondvalue;

    protected object _lock = new object();

    public event System.EventHandler ValueChanged;
    public event System.EventHandler SecondValueChange;

    protected virtual void OnValueChange()
    {  
        lock (this._lock)
        {
        EventHandler eventvaluechange = ValueChanged;
            if (eventvaluechange != null)
                eventvaluechange(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnSecondValueChange()
    {
        lock (this._lock)
        {
            EventHandler eventvaluechange = SecondValueChange;
            if (eventvaluechange != null)
                eventvaluechange(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.value)
            {//if value changed enter
                this.value = value;
                OnValueChange();
            }
        }
    }
    public int Secondvalue
    {
        get { return this.secondvalue; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.secondvalue)
            {//if value changed enter
                this.secondvalue = value;
                OnSecondValueChange();
            }
        }        
    }
   }
   }
```

Do I need two lock (lock1 and lock2 object or only one for both value and secondvalue....?
Thanks a lot.

---

## Update

Ok let's do it so.
I'm using beckhoff PLC which are real time Task PLC. and I'm reading two value on it when the value change. like this:
Form1 Class:

```
 namespace RealTimeLock
 {
   using Beckhoff.App.Ads.Core;
   using Beckhoff.App.Ads.Core.Plc;
   using TwinCAT.Ads;
   using System.IO;  
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PLC PLCData;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(IBAAdsServer _adsServer)
        : this()
    {
        PLCData = new PLC(_adsServer);

        PLCData.ErrorBoolChanged += new EventHandler(EventErrorChanged);//error info
        PLCData.ForceValChanged += new EventHandler(EventForceChanged);//Force input info
    }
    protected virtual void EventErrorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //state of error PLC
        lv_ErrorInfo.Text = "PLC Error num : " + PLCData.i_ErrorID.ToString();
    }
    protected virtual void EventForceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//modify graphical data PLC Force data
        lv_ForceInfo.Text = PLCData.i_ForceVal.ToString();
        c_graphForceIN.Series["ForceData"].Points.AddY(PLCData.i_ForceVal);
        if (c_graphForceIN.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum - 10 > c_graphForceIN.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size)
        {
            c_graphForceIN.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Scroll(c_graphForceIN.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum);
            c_graphForceIN.Series["ForceData"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Error ID and Force change showed in Form1 label lv_ErrorID and lv_Force and graphForceIN add point.

The events handler on the other side (PLC class) looks like this:
PLC Class:

```
 namespace RealTimeLock
  {
  using Beckhoff.App.Ads.Core;
  using Beckhoff.App.Ads.Core.Plc;
  using TwinCAT.Ads;
  using System.IO;  
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PLC PLCData;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(IBAAdsServer _adsServer)
        : this()
    {
        PLCData = new PLC(_adsServer);

        PLCData.ErrorBoolChanged += new EventHandler(EventErrorChanged);//error info
        PLCData.ForceValChanged += new EventHandler(EventForceChanged);//Force input info
    }
    protected virtual void EventErrorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //state of error PLC
        lv_ErrorInfo.Text = "PLC Error num : " + PLCData.i_ErrorID.ToString();
    }
    protected virtual void EventForceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//modify graphical data PLC Force data
        lv_ForceInfo.Text = PLCData.i_ForceVal.ToString();
        c_graphForceIN.Series["ForceData"].Points.AddY(PLCData.i_ForceVal);
        if (c_graphForceIN.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum - 10 > c_graphForceIN.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size)
        {
            c_graphForceIN.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Scroll(c_graphForceIN.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum);
            c_graphForceIN.Series["ForceData"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Does it seem to be correct coding for you guys? and while I have a real time task running there do I need to lock variables and if so, do I need two lock or only one??
Thanks for your remark on this!!

Comment: Do you mean multiple *event handlers*? Do you know that you are getting multiple threads? Also, the example code you've given doesn't seem to have any concurrency issues - I assume you real code does?

Comment: I changed the code so that we have something correct to talk about. I'm waiting your answers. thanks

Comment: Where are your threads being created?

Comment: first thread is form1 (automatically created) second one is Task_1.

Comment: There really doesn't seem to be any need to use a `lock` in your code. I cannot see where more than one thread could be causing a threading issue. There just isn't a concurrency issue here.

Comment: And now? I pass some times to show you the real problem. Thanks for your remarks!

Comment: Awesome - you don't need locks at all. You just need to invoke the calls back to the UI thread.

Comment: You shouldn't edit questions like this. I'll clean it up for you and show you how you should evolve your question.

Comment: Thanks! Why did you say Awesome? It's clear now for the question update thanks! Concerning the invoke calls in the ui thread I wonder, because I have some classes in my program and I think it would be unreadeable if I put all those event call in the main Form.... How could I do that.

Comment: It's awesome that you don't need locks as locking means that things are getting complicated and potentially buggy. And with `"Concerning the invoke calls in the ui thread I wonder, because I have some classes in my program and I think it would be unreadeable if I put all those event call in the main Form"` I don't know what you mean?

Comment: Sorry. misunderstanding between us, I got it now. Thanks for the help!